# Decision trees minimizing the Gini error

Tags: cart, gini

I was reading the *Elements of Statistical Learning* and I stumbled upon the formula for minimizing the misclassification error. I was wondering if I could write something like that for the [Gini index](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gini_coefficient).

The [CART](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/cart/info) algorithm begins by considering splitting on variable $j$ and split point $s$, and defines the regions

$$R_1 = \{X \in \mathbb{R}^d : X_j \le s \}, R_2 = \{X \in \mathbb{R}^d : X_j > s \}$$

The Gini index is a measure of the impurity in each regions denoted as:

$$GI(R_j) = \sum_{k=1}^{K} \hat{p}_k(R_j) [1 - \hat{p}_k(R_j)]$$

A completely pure node would have a Gini index of $0$ and would mean that it mostly contains points from one class.

We then greedily chooses $j,s$ by minimizing the weighted Gini error.
We have to define $N_{R_1}$ is the number of data points in region $R_1$ and $N_{R_2}$ is the number of data points in region $R_2$

$$\underset{j,s}{\text{argmin}} \Big( N_{R_1}GI(R_1) + N_{R_2}GI(R_2)   \Big)$$

with

$$\hat{p}_k(R_j) = \frac{1}{n_j} \sum_{x_i \in R_j} 1 \{y_i=k \}$$

Each region $R_j$ contains some subset of the training data, $n_j$ points.

**Is my application of the CART algorithm to the Gini index correct?**

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: is it correct what I have written ? Or incorrect ? I have never seen any equivalent formula on a book for the argmin